# how to back up mysql database using vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

all this code is working...
this is my code in my back up...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Process.Start("C:\xampplite\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe", " -u root -p db_hrm -r ""C:\Users\Rodmar\Desktop\Desktop.sql""")

End Sub
```

and this is my code in restore

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim myProcess As New Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\xampplite\mysql\bin"
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.Start()
    Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
    Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
    myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql.exe -u root -p db_hrm < C:\Users\Rodmar\Desktop\Desktop.sql")
    myStreamWriter.Close()
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
    myProcess.Close()
    'Process.Start("C:\porgram files\mysql\bin\mysql.exe", "-u username -p password --database=dbname > -r ""C:\back.sql""")

End Sub
```

the question is.how to backup the database and choose the file location to where you want to save it. and how to restore it to where i saved my database.

Comment: Sounds like you want us to write some code for you. Read up on building a Windows Forms app with controls other than buttons, and come back to use when you've done some modicum of work.